# Add items from ArrayList to Array and show in JList

Tags: arrays, arraylist, jlist

I am trying to add all the items from `ArrayList<String>` to `String[]` array which is in another class but i am fail to do that. I have tried many of the ways but to not avail. The String[] array in another class does not display any item. Hence, I was fail to add the array to the `JList`. I have no idea to deal with it. Here is my code:

```js
public class bookbook extends JFrame{
  java.util.List<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();

  public bookbook(){
    selectTime.timeArr = new String[ timeList.size() ];
    timeList.toArray(selectTime.timeArr);
  }
}
```

```js
public class SelectTime extends JFrame{
  String[] timeArr = {};
  private JList jlstTime = new JList(timeArr);

  public SelectTime(){
    jpTicket.add(jlstTime);
  }
}
```

I really need your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the `JList` array directly, which, as the documentation states, will result in an undefined behaviour. Try this code: Added the function `updateList` to the class `SelectTime` to do it using the appropiate methods

```
 public class bookbook extends JFrame{
      java.util.List<String> timeList = new ArrayList<String>();

      public bookbook(){
        String [] timeArr = new String[ timeList.size() ];
        timeList.toArray(selectTime.timeArr);
        selectTime.updateList(timeArr);
      }
    }
```

-

```
public class SelectTime extends JFrame{
  String[] timeArr = {};
  private JList jlstTime = new JList(timeArr);

  public SelectTime(){
    jpTicket.add(jlstTime);
  }

  public void updateList(String [] array)
  {
      jlstTime.setListData(array);
      jlstTime.invalidate();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's really work! The JList is now filled with ithems. Thanks for your help!